# Replace varying pattern in multiple rows

Tags: r, web-scraping, gsub, stringr

I have a data frame (Catcher2) using scraped data. For the `MarketValue` column I would just like the prices of each person e.g. 40,00 Mill. €

I have tried to use `gsub()` but I cannot remove all the information past the '€'. There is also the issue that the dates varying between the players. Is there some code I can use to run through the whole data frame rather than a code line for each date?

[image: Dataframe Table]

Comment: Please don't use images of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` function with the following code:

```
x <- "40,00 Mill. € Last change"
sub("\\€.*", "€", x)
[1] "40,00 Mill. €"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following gsub command using regex with a negative lookbehind for the dollar sign to mark its position and remove everything after it.

```
Catcher2$MarketValue <- gsub("(?<=\\$).*","", as.character(Catcher2$MarketValue), perl = T)
```

Comment: The solution with the `sub()` function proposed by [Barbara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7562411/barbara) is much faster than mine and a better solution for your simple case. Hence, only use the regex solution if you need to extract more complex patterns.